# AppleScript terminology: Ways to target a specific object

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to make this AppleScript work with my scriptable app:

```
tell application "My App"
    tell thing 1    -- my custom class
        dosomething -- my custom command
    end tell
end tell
```

I like the command to affect "thing 1". Is that even possible?

Or am I required to add a parameter to the command like this:

```
tell application "My App"
    dosomething with thing 1
end tell
```

I'd rather use the first option, though.

BTW, in case others are struggling with Object-first commands: It's important to leave the command's "class" field empty and only set the method name in the `<responds-to>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Object-first command and implement the `direct-parameter` key passing the type of your custom class.

The `<responds-to>` Cocoa method takes one parameter

```
- (void)dosomething:(NSScriptCommand *)command
```

Comment: That would be the way to implement "dosomething with thing 1", right? That won't work with my first approach, it appears, so it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: No, that's the way to write `tell thing 1 to do something`